# Android : ContextMenu and LongClick issue

Tags: android, listview, nullpointerexception, contextmenu, onlongclicklistener

I've got a listview filled with personnal views. I want to create a menu when I make a long click on an item. Therefore I have this in onCreate :

```
    myListView.setOnCreateContextMenuListener(new View.OnCreateContextMenuListener(){

        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu cMenu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
                MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
                inflater.inflate(R.menu.song_menu, cMenu);
    }});

    myListView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener(){

        public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int pos, long id) {
        lastOnLongClickedPos = pos;
        Log.v("test pos", currentList.getSong(lastOnLongClickedPos).getTitle());
        return false;
        }

    });
```

getSong is used to get a instance of a SongContainer (class with title, path, artist, etc). Everything is ok by now, I do get the song according to the position.

The problem appears when I want to do specific actions (read song, add to playlist etc). I have this code in the class (outside the onCreate) :

public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

```
    final String clickedMusic;
    Uri uriSong;

    switch(item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.songlist_play : 
            clickedMusic = currentList.getSong(lastOnLongClickedPos).getPath();
            uriSong = Uri.parse("file://" + clickedMusic);
            // send uri to player
            return true;
    [...]
```

In this function, the currentList seems to be empty since the line "                clickedMusic = currentList.getSong(lastOnLongClickedPos).getPath();" makes me get a nullpointer exception. I already tested lastOnLongClickedPos and it's ok. So the fact is my currentList is different in those 2 functions, and I really don't know why !
Any idea plz ? :x

Comment: When are you initiating your currentList ?